# How to move the collection view cell below battery icon in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionviewcell

This may be a dumb question. In books, it shows the following screenshot for collection view cell,

[image: good one]!

You can see the collection view cell is below the battery icon.

However, when I tried it in storyboard, it is shown as below.

[image: bad one]!

The collection view cell overlap the batter icon line.

It seems I can not move the collection view cell.

How to move it a little bit below the battery icon line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put following condition of frame of `UICollectionView`.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) 
   collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 20, width, height)];         
else          
   collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, width, height)];
```

For deeply understand refer following question/answer;

[iOS 7 status bar overlapping UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886195/ios-7-status-bar-overlapping-ui)
[iOS 7 - Status bar overlaps the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view)
[Status bar and navigation bar issue in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7/19025547#19025547)
[Storyboard-set iOS 7 Status Bar not shown in right style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035792/storyboard-set-ios-7-status-bar-not-shown-in-right-style)
[Storyboard app run on iOS 7 OK but Navbar shift view on iOS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749499/storyboard-app-run-on-ios-7-ok-but-navbar-shift-view-on-ios-6-1)